# how to serialize a point3D using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

```
public class Placement 
{
   public Point3D Location { get; set; }
   public Point3D Axis { get; set; }
   public Point3D Direction { get; set; }
}


public class Attribute1
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public Type Type { get; set; }
  public Object Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Attribute1 a =  new Attribute1();
     a.Key = "test";
     var p = new Placement();
     p.Axis = new Point3D(12.0, 22.09, 0);
     p.Location = new Point3D(12.0, 22.09, 0);
     p.Direction = new Point3D(12.0, 22.09, 0);

     a.Value = p;
     var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Attribute1));
     var path = "E:\\details.xml";
     using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
     {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, a);
     }

     Console.Read();
   }    
}
```

I am trying to serialize `Point3D` using `XmlSerializer`.
I am using `XmlSerializer` for serializing other properties of the class which contain `Attribute1`
But I get error while serializing.
Please let me know how to achieve this or point me to relevant resources. Thanks!

Comment: `I get error while serializing` But you think the error message is unrelated and therefore you don't post it don't you?

Comment: Yes the error message is `There was an error generating the XML document`

Comment: But there is an inner exception explaining details....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have told it that you want to serialize Attribute1 but not Placement. Just change this one line:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Attribute1), new Type[] { typeof(Placement) });
```